# How to add JQuery after Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are containers that have dropdowns, initialized using materializecss

```js
$('.dropdown-button').dropdown({
        inDuration: 300,
        outDuration: 225,
        constrain_width: true, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
        hover: false, // Activate on click
        alignment: 'right', // Aligns dropdown to left or right edge (works with constrain_width)
        gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
        belowOrigin: false // Displays dropdown below the button
    });
```

Later I add more containers to the page using ajax, but Dropdowns do not work on them anymore ...

How to fix it?

Comment: You have to add dropdown init() in .success cb at ajax, show me ajax, and i write solution

Comment: You need to call that `dropdown()` method again on the elements which are appended after your AJAX call.

Comment: @Legendary I use django-endless-pagination, so i haven't written any ajax, it is just provided... Is there any way to modify it?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, but how?

Comment: I don't know, as you've not given us your code.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I use django-endless-pagination, so i haven't written any ajax, it is just provided... Is there any way to modify it?